# Total Visitors on a SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, web-analytics

I have a requirement for getting the count of visitors who visits a SharePoint site in a year and as well as in a month. I want to display the result as a webpart in the homepage. Also I want to create another webpart to display the details of total visitors including name and profile picture. Can you please help me to complete these two webpart ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

To display the count of unique users for site, you may need to develop a web part to get the unique users for site from usage report programmatically, then display the data.

In SharePoint 2013, usage report can be obtain programmatically using [SearchServiceApplication class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.searchserviceapplication.aspx), from Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.dll.

There are two methods available for these:

•   [GetSearchReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.searchserviceapplication.getsearchreport.aspx)

•   [GetRollupAnalyticsItemData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.searchserviceapplication.getrollupanalyticsitemdata.aspx)

A demo code which retrieves the daily and monthly usage reports of Unique Users count:

```
 using (var site = new SPSite(siteId))
       {
         var context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
         var searchProxy = context.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as       SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
         var usageData= searchProxy.GetRollupAnalyticsItemData(1,Guid.Empty,site.ID,Guid.Empty); 
usageData.GetUniqueUsersCountForDay(date);
        usageData.GetUniqueUsersCountForMonth(date);
        }
```

Some blogs about retrieving the reports programmatically:

[How to retrieve reports programmatically in SharePoint 2013](https://radutut.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/how-to-get-search-analytics-reports-programmatically-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[How to get Search Analytics Reports programmatically in SharePoint 2013](http://girishkumarms.blogspot.com/2015/07/get-search-analytics-reports.html)

[An example about how to display the number of view count in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Step-by-steps-on-how-to-display-Most-Visited-Sites-with-number-of-view-count-in-SharePoint-2013-Web-Analytics)

It is difficult to get the visitors who access the site in SharePoint 2013. You may need to parse the IIS logs using LogParser. Analyze logs to find the visitors.

Here is a custom tool to analyze IIS logs and get visitors for SharePoint sites by analyzing IIS logs:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/The-SharePoint-Flavored-5b03f323#content